# SQL - VARCHAR to date where the separator is a period not a dash SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, format, varchar

I have a VARCHAR field, well many in fact in my SQL tables where the date is a VARCHAR in the following format YYYY.MM.DD

I have started with VARCHAR(REPLACE(mc.CANXREASONDATE, '.', '-') but I dont know how to change this then to a date

I have googled but cannot find the answer

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is your SQL database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.)?  Date operations in SQL are highly database specific.

Comment: Not sure why your search engine is not working, but my have all results that I need when I search: change column type (your database)

Answer (score 0):

Try `cast()`ing to a date:

```
CAST(REPLACE(mc.CANXREASONDATE, '.', '-' AS DATE)
```

The format YYYY-MM-DD is an ISO 8601 standard date format that *most* but not all databases recognize.

If you actually want to change the date column itself, you can use `ALTER TABLE`, with syntax such as:

```
ALTER TABLE mc ALTER COLUMN CANXREASONDATE DATE
```

Of course, the exact syntax of these statements may vary depending on the database.  But this should give you some direction.

EDIT:

In SQL Server, you can find bad values using:

```
SELECT mc.CANXREASONDATE
FROM mc
WHERE TRY_CAST(REPLACE(mc.CANXREASONDATE, '.', '-' AS DATE) IS NULL;
```

You can use either `TRY_CAST()` in your query or fix the data.

Comment: Using SQL server

Tried 

select 

CAST(REPLACE(mc.CANXREASONDATE, '.', '-' ) as DATE)

from [ACTA].[MATERIAL_CHAR] mc

got the following error

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The column canxreasonedate is (VARCHAR(10),null) so I am presuming the nulls are causing it to fail

Comment: try_cast is not a valid function in our version f SQL server

Comment: @lyng . . . Then you are not using a supported version of SQL Server -- or your compatibility mode is set to some unsupported version.

Comment: Its SQL Server 2008 which I think is why it is not working, we are just going through an upgrade

Comment: @lyng . . . If you cannot wait until you upgrade, then a calendar table is probably the best solution.